# Create 2d/3d matrix "object" from data columns and plot it further as contour plot

Tags: r, matrix, ggplot2

i got actually stuck in this case already on creating the matrix. Lets start with the data first:

```
   Length Diameter Defect Start Defect End Defect Location Defect Angle
1   9850      100          975        987             986            0
2   9850      100         1937       1949             709            0
3   9850      100         4775       4787             604            0
4   9850      100         5775       5787              15            0
5   9850      100         6062       6087              44           -3
6   9850      100         6325       6337             385            0
7   9850      100         6650       6675             588            0
```

And here is the Input:

```
structure(list(Length = c(9850, 9850, 9850, 9850, 9850, 9850, 
9850), Diameter = c(100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100), `Defect Start` = c(975, 
1937, 4775, 5775, 6062, 6325, 6650), `Defect End` = c(987, 1949, 
4787, 5787, 6087, 6337, 6675), `Defect Location` = c(986, 709, 
604, 15, 44, 385, 588), `Defect Angle` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, -3, 0, 
0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

and graphical explanation of the data is below (quick paint solution)

[image]

**Goal**

The Goal is to create a 2d or 3d plot using for example **contour plot** (x axis Length, y axis Diameter or so), to show the position of the defects (defects are always simple lines with **start** *Defect Start* and **end** *Defect End* **positions in length** and *Defect Location* in a **width**) in a roll.

I have stuck on preparing the Matrix and i have actually no idea if it is even possible to do it in R but i guess it would be great and interesting aproach to check out!

If You have any tips i would appreciate it!

Comment: if Diameter = 100, how can the defect location be > 100 * pi ? Where does the 1240 in your crawing come from?

Comment: Exactly thats what i have been asking myself too! This is the data that comes from machine that measures the defects and has been set up like that by the workers without even making sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea.

Plot each pipe as a 2d rectangle, on which you show the defects.

to be done:
-figure out what the `Defect Location` means
-is the angle needed?

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- mydata %>%
  #give the pipe an id
  mutate( id = 1 ) %>%
  group_by( id ) %>%
  #give each defect (by pipe) an id
  mutate( defect_id = row_number() ) %>%
  #not sure what to do woith defect location.... 
  #to get it inside the pipe, i divide by 10... needs looking into!!
  mutate( `Defect Location` = `Defect Location` / 10 ) %>%
  gather("defect", "x", -Length, -Diameter, -`Defect Angle`, -id, -defect_id, -`Defect Location`)


ggplot( data = df ) + 
  #draw pipe as a 2D rectangle, height = pi * Diameter
  geom_rect( aes( xmin = 0, xmax = Length, ymin = 0, ymax = pi * Diameter ), alpha = 0.1 ) +
  #draw start-endpoint and lines with defects
  geom_point( aes( x = x, y = `Defect Location`, group = as.character(defect_id) ), color = "red", size = 2 ) +
  geom_line( aes( x = x, y = `Defect Location`, group = as.character(defect_id), colour = as.character(defect_id) ), color = "red", size = 2 ) +
  #draw each pipe
  facet_wrap( ~id, ncol = 1 )
```

[image]

Comment: That already looks good! Just instead of Points the line would be better (showing the length of the defect)

Comment: Defects are very short in relation to the total x... so lines would not change much in the output (in this example)

Comment: @Mal_a lines added in updated answer... image does not change, but try with different sample data and watch the lines appear :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for help!